# Can't install 15.10 on my laptop

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, nouveau, resolvconf

I upgraded from 15.04 and the upgrade seemed to go alright. It won't boot now --- x windows crashes. I tried running it from a root shell after enabling networking, but that doesn't work: resolvconf doesn't get started and crashes every time I try to start it manually.

I bit the bullet and tried to clean-install from the DVD but that won't boot. I get a grub line giving me the option to try Ubuntu or install it, but whatever option I pick give a huge list of  nouveau error messages and the POST screen reappears.

The 15.04 -> 15.10 upgrade experience has not been a pleasant one, as it crashed on three other computers. I thought I was in good shape because it ran to completion on my laptop, but no such luck.

Comment: As my post implies, I've had no trouble running 15.04. The laptop is an ASUS ROG G56JK-EB72 Gaming Laptop.

Comment: I solved this problem by installing Debian Stable. It Just Works.